# adding instances from django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

This is how my classes look.

```
class School(models.Model):
    state = models.ForeignKey(State, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    region = models.ForeignKey(Region, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cluster = models.ForeignKey(Cluster, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    school_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    facilitator = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    f_number = models.IntegerField()
    f_email = models.EmailField()
    school_logo = models.FileField(default='')
    school_strength = models.IntegerField()
```

In which state, region, cluster are also classes. I have tried to create a network of schools with classification in 3 levels i.e state, region, cluster.
I have assumed that when I add schools from django admin I thought it might filter regions if I select state and filter clusters when I select region so that it would be easy. But It doesn't seem to work. Though after selecting a particular state and region while adding a school in the cluster dropdown all the clusters from all the states and regions are coming.

Is there a solution for this or as of now we don't have such option in django?

Comment: Interesting question. I want to know as well if this is possible.

Comment: That would really help admins to manage stuff in their websites. let's hope someone will come up with a solution.

Comment: @PabloVergés, I have answered this, hope it helps you!!!

Comment: I too faced this problem, but then I used `smart-selects` and it was wonderful then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try **ChainedForeignKey** from [django-smart-selects](https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects) package it works like a magic.

### Installation of smart_selects

```
pip install django-smart-selects
```

**project settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS=[
    . . . . .
    . . . . .
    'smart_selects',
    . . . . .
]
```

**project urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    . . . . .
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^chaining/', include('smart_selects.urls')),
    . . . . .
]
```

See the [installation of django-smart-selects](https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects#installation)

### Working of ChainedForeignKey

```
from smart_selects.db_fields import *

class State(models.Model):
    stateName = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    . . . . 

class Region(models.Model):
    state = models.ForeignKey(State, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    regionName = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    . . . . .
    . . . . .


class Cluster(models.Model):
    state = models.ForeignKey(State, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    region = ChainedForeignKey(Region,chained_field="state",chained_model_field="state", show_all=False, auto_choose=True, sort=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    clusterName = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    . . . . .
    . . . . .  



class school(models.Model):
    state = models.ForeignKey(State, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    region = ChainedForeignKey(Region, chained_field="state",chained_model_field="state", show_all=False, auto_choose=True, sort=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cluster = ChainedForeignKey(Cluster, chained_field="region",chained_model_field="region", show_all=False, auto_choose=True, sort=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    schoolName = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    . . . . 
    . . . .
```

Try this, it works so well in `admin area`.

Comment: How to use it?
I'm a beginner :p

Comment: Ok wait I am giving you details

Comment: @PabloVergés, Did you got what you were searching for?

Comment: Thank you very much. It is working absolutely fine. Everything is cool but I am just curious to know why all the sub child classes have chainedforiegnkey but not the direct child class?

Comment: @venkatmanisai, If it helps then please vote up and select the answer. Thanks for cooperation.

Comment: You can go to that link for more info.